# DialogBoxParam didn't work on 64-bit platform

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, dialog

I am porting my code to 64-bit platform.but I get a problem with DialogBoxParam.it work fine with 32-bit platform but not 64-bit.I used it like below

```
DialogBoxParam(Hinstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(DLG_INPUTBOX),owner,@DialogProc,NativeInt(@info))
```

DLG_INPUTBOX come from the resource file

unit resource_gui;

interface

```
CONST
  DLG_INPUTBOX = 8810;

  DLG_PROGRESS = 8800;

  DLG_AREYOUSURE = 8809;

  BITMPAT_UNCHECKED = 8804;

  BITMPAT_CHECKED = 8805;
{$R DLGRES.res}
```

here is the dialogpro

```
  function DialogProc(hwndDlg:HWND;uMsg:UINT ;wParam:WPARAM ;lParam:LPARAM ):NativeInt;stdcall;
  var
    info:Pinfo;
    OldEditValue:String;
    CanClose:boolean;
  begin
    Result := EIINT(0);
    case uMsg of
      WM_INITDIALOG:begin
        setWindowLong(hwndDlg,GWL_USERDATA,lParam);
      end;
      WM_SHOWWINDOW:begin
      .......
```

I set a breakpoint in the  WM_INITDIALOG code block but it didn't come in

Comment: SetWindowLong should be SetWindowLongPtr. Otherwise, I cannot see anything wrong? What error checking code do you have? Can we have an SSCCE?

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

[DialogBoxParam - works in win32, but doesn‎](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/45989a10-2785-486d-94ae-4f1f3e1ca651/)

> I've been changing my code to 64 bit and came across my DialogBox Procedures. The call I made to DialogBoxParam to initialize the dialog box would no longer compile in 64 bit, so I changed my procedures from returning BOOL to returning INT_PTR.
>
> Now when I run my code, my dialog box never shows up.
>   I put a break point in the DialogBox Procedure and it get:
>
> WM_SETFONT
>   WM_DESTROY
>   WM_NCDESTROY
>
> messages in that order. I never receive a WM_INITDIALOG message at all anymore!
>
> My call to DialogBoxParam returns -1 and GetLastError returns 0

> I had the exact same problem today. I found that my manifest file had the wrong processor architecture associated with it.
>
> processorArchitecture="x86"
>
> instead of
>
> processorArchitecture="amd64"
>
> Once I fixed that, the dialogbox popped up as expected.